# A statement on prehilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X , \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$ be a prehilbert space and let $M \subset X$ be a vector subspace such that $(M , {\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}_M)$ is a Hilbert space, being
$$
{\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}_M = {\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}\big|_{M \times M} : M \times M \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C} \mbox{)}\mbox{.}
$$
I have to show that $(X , \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$ is a Hilbert space if and only if $\left(M^{\perp} , {\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}_{M^{\perp}}\right)$ is a Hilbert space, being
$$
{\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}_{M^{\perp}} = {\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle}\big|_{M^{\perp} \times M^{\perp}} : M^{\perp} \times M^{\perp} \to \mathbb{R} \mbox{ (or } \mathbb{C} \mbox{)}\mbox{.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a Hilbert space, then $M^\perp$ as well, as $M^\perp$ is closed.

Assume $M^\perp$ to be a Hilbert space. Let $P_M$ and $P_{M^\perp}$ denote the orthogonal projections onto $M$ and $M^\perp$, respectively.
Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then $(P_MX_n)$ and $(P_{M^\perp}x_n)$ are Cauchy sequences and hence convergent. Then also $x_n = P_MX_n + P_{M^\perp}x_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Ok thank you and can your answer help me to show that, given $x \in X$,
$$
\|x - u\| = \inf \{\|x - z\| : z \in M^{\perp}\}\mbox{,}
$$
where $u = x - P_M(x)$?

Comment: This should always be true.

Comment: Can you help me to prove that, please?